# RecyclerView scrolls up when items change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

When Adapter submit a new list the screen scrolls up. How don't scroll the srcreen when submit a new list?

obs: setHasFixedSize(false)

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_on_primary">
    

                   ...


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/matchesRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
            tools:itemCount="5"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_match" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```